# VB If statement in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net

I'm converting an old timed script from VB to C# and I need help with understanding what an `If` statement's purpose is.

The code I need help with is:

```
... And If(cp.JobTitle, String.Empty) = String.Empty And ...
```

This is part of a SQL query and the `cp.JobTitle` in the database is nullable string field.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not part of a SQL query. Perhaps it's part of a LINQ query or some code that constructs a SQL query but there's nothing to do with SQL there.

Anyway, that VB code is using the `If` operator with two operands. The equivalent of this VB:

```vb
If(cp.JobTitle, String.Empty) = String.Empty
```

is this C#:

```cs
(cp.JobTitle ?? string.Empty) == string.Empty
```

It's saying to use `cp.JobTitle` unless it's `Nothing`, in which case use `String.Empty`. A better way to write functionally equivalent VB would be this:

```vb
String.IsNullOrEmpty(cp.JobTitle)
```

I hope the equivalent C# to that is obvious.

By the way, that VB code really ought to be using `AndAlso` rather than `And`. If you would use `&&` in C# rather than `&`, which pretty much everyone would, then you should be using `AndAlso` in VB rather than `And`. In both cases, you should only use the other if you explicitly don't want short-circuiting.

Comment: @Jonh Thanks! Yes I should've said LINQ and thanks for your reply things are much clearer now. I'm using && in C#.